# How to handle multiple cropped images from the main one image if we cut them with the copy crop (image package)?

Tags: flutter, image

I'm using mlkit to detect multiple object In an image, so I'm using this image package to cut but when encoded 'addFiles[i].writeAsBytes(encodePng(finalCroppedImage[i]));' like this they ask me to insert a file to put the cropped image inside of it, but I have one image with three cropped one, so how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Maybe consider using all the results. Or just pick the first one if they are all similar. But if all of them were picked up by mlkit, you maybe need all of them.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad what i mean that the mlkit detects 3 objects in a image, then i'm trying to cut these objects using the image package, but what's happening is that i want to put File image first and then i only can override it with only one cropped image, but i have 3 cropped images, where should i save the 2 left ?

Comment: Do you need to save them? Create a for loop, for the number of objects returned from mlkit. If you post your code it would be easier to help

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad.  no i don;t want to save i just have 3 coordinate that returned from ml kit now i want to crop the image according to the coordinate and then the result should be 3 cropped images. how to set these 3 cropped image into a variables? and i have only one main image path.. final a = await File(mainImage!.path)
          .writeAsBytes(encodePng(finalCroppedImage[i]));

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad please refer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72551044/in-the-image-package-we-can-crop-image-with-specific-coordinates-and-can-be-retu